# How to change html background dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the background of my webpage gradually from red to white within 5 seconds in a gradient manner. How do I acheive that? CSS? javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use javascript [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) functions.

For example

```
setTimeout("changeBackground()",3000); // call changeBackground() function , 3 seconds later.
```

Comment: How about multiple colors? I tried put two in a row but only the 2nd got called.
setTimeout("changeC('#071918')",500);
setTimeout("changeC('#0A2A29')",500);

Comment: `setTimeout("changeC('#071918')",500); setTimeout("changeC('#0A2A29')",1000); ` **First line : change color 0.5 second later. Second line : change color : 1 second later (after page loading)** So, colors will change every 0.5 second.